# How can I delete from a duplicates subquery in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a query in Access that finds duplicate records. I want to delete them. I assume the best way to do this is with a DELETE subquery, but nothing I do seems to work.

My Query for finding duplicates is:

```
SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, count(*)
FROM [work]
GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

There are many more fields though and a primary key. Any syntax I try does not seem to do what I want. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what errors have you gotten? Also, It would be a lot easier if we knew how the table looked and if there are any FKC's to be aware of etc.

Comment: are you planning on deleting all the records returned, or do you want to leave one of each duplicate set?

Comment: @LudvigRydahl I have tried to create a DELETE subquery. So I don't have it anymore because it didn't work.

It was just delete on databasename (subquery) results.

Comment: @Stephen I want to delete all of the records that are returned by my select.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to try this on a different database than Access, and you'll see in this answer why. But you asked of Access, so here goes:

So we have this table, which contains Mister Dent and Ms McMillan twice:

```
CREATE TABLE work ( 
  division         INT
, fips_county_code VARCHAR(3)
, last             VARCHAR(10)
, suffix           VARCHAR(3)
, first            VARCHAR(6)
, title            VARCHAR(16) 
, birthdate        DATE
);

INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Dent'      ,'','Arthur','Earthling'       ,'1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Prefect'   ,'','Ford'  ,'HH Guide Scout'  ,'1925-04-01');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'N/A','Beeblebrox','','Zaphod','Galaxy President','1857-09-13');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'McMillan'  ,'','Tricia','Astrophysicist'  ,'1959-09-29');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'Dent'      ,'','Arthur','Earthling'       ,'1957-08-02');
INSERT INTO work VALUES(1,'UK' ,'McMillan'  ,'','Tricia','Astrophysicist'  ,'1959-09-29');
```

I suppose you don't want to remove both occurrences of each Mr. Dent or Ms. McMillan, but keep one of the copies.

Independent of the database, you won't be able to just DELETE just one of two identical rows. (strange that you should have a primary key, though; you'd never have two identical rows with a working primary key).

In an better database, you would:

```
ALTER TABLE work RENAME TO work_with_dups;
CREATE TABLE work AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM work_with_dups;
DROP TABLE work_with_dups;
```

But you're stuck with Access. I suggest you'd try to mimick as much as possible of the above with the limited possibilities you have.

No rename possible, and no CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT possible. So let's create a new table with identical structure as the first, and fill it with all of the `work` table:

```
CREATE TABLE work_with_dups( 
  division         INT
, fips_county_code VARCHAR(3)
, last             VARCHAR(10)
, suffix           VARCHAR(3)
, first            VARCHAR(6)
, title            VARCHAR(16) 
, birthdate        DATE
);
INSERT INTO work_with_dups SELECT * FROM work;
```

Now, we clean the original table ...

```
DELETE FROM work;
```

And we fill it with the de-duped content of the previously saved `work_with_dups` :

```
INSERT INTO work SELECT DISTINCT * FROM work_with_dups;
```

And finally we clean up our mess:

```
DROP TABLE work_with_dups;
```

Clumsy, but it works ...

Marco the Sane

Comment: Wow. This is crazy, but I can see it working... 
I don't have a ton of choice but to use Access unfortunately.